# Body does not scroll on overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I add a div whose height is bigger than the page size, the body does not scroll even though I have added `overflow:scroll`. I even tried over overflow:auto;

[JSFiddle here.](https://fiddle.jshell.net/se65eqm8/)

Comment: You added position fixed to #first. change that to relative.

Comment: on doing that div dissapers

Comment: You want to scroll fixed element? strange..

Comment: You have added css position fixed twice to #first, so might not able fix by removing first occurrence. remove from both the places

Answer (score 0):

Add height 100%

```
#first {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;/* Add This*/
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/se65eqm8/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use following css with position relative for first.

```
     #first:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  background-color: #191919;
  width: 500vh;
  height: 200vh;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  overflow: auto;
}

#first {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 #first {
   z-index: 0;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```